# How to do a Laravel 5 database search but return all if the page has loaded without a search

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am looking to create a customer page with a search bar. If no search has taken place **all** will be returned. The code below shows what is in my controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
     {
          if(($term = $request->get('term'))){
              $customers = customers::where('name', 'like', '%' .$term.'%'); 
          }
            else{
              $customers = customers::all();  
            }     
         return view ("customers.index")->with('customers',$customers);

}
```

All is returned upon loading but upon searching nothing is displayed in the table in the view.
There are no errors and the form is passing the data it just doesn't load the data in the view after searching.

Below is the code for the view.

```
<tbody>

                @foreach ($customers as $customer)

                    <tr>
                        <th>{{$customer->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$customer->business}}</td>
                        <td>{{$customer->name}}</td>
                        <td><a href="{{ route ('customers.show', $customer->id)}}" class="btn btn-default">View</a></td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "it just doesn't load the data in the view", then show us the view ? :)

Comment: Thanks @MartinHenriksen I have updated the question. The view is working when display all but not once queried.

Comment: if you use the dd(); command on customers before return what does it print?

Comment: It prints the array for the data in the table, the same data that prints correctly for the 'else' query.

Comment: Have also done this for the $term variable and that is reaching the controller without a problem. @MartinHenriksen

Comment: It seems weird it works in one scenario, hmm what about printing $customers before the foreach loop?

Comment: So I have taken the else out and run dd(); on $customers and it is returning undefinable variable. So looks as if there is a problem with the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `get()` method at the end of your search. It should be:

```
$customers = customers::where('name', 'like', '%' .$term.'%')->get();
```

Which will return a [`collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models) based on the results.

Comment: Thank you, was just reading this is in the docs as you replied. Appreciated!

Comment: @JamesParsons glad I could help. Since it's the last thing you type, it's easy to forget...speaking from experience :)

Comment: Just getting used to Eloquent as much as possible so missing little bits. Perfect all working!